# Reading like "list = [][][]" lists from couple of txt files

Tags: python, list

I have 9 txt files. Every text is like:

```
 [(0.0, 32.633221, 39.91769),
  (8.32, 32.633717, 39.917892),
  (25.35, 32.633945, 39.917538),
  (25.93, 32.634262, 39.916946),
  (7.24, 32.634888, 39.91674),
  (0.0, 32.635014, 39.916737),
  (15.31, 32.635242, 39.916569),
  (22.12, 32.635727, 39.916176)....
```

I want to create a new text file that contains only the first elements of every element. I mean like:

```
list_firsttxtfile = [(0.0), (8.32), (25.35), (25.93),... ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way of doing it.

```
list_firsttxtfile = []

with open("mytextfile.txt", "r") as f:
    data = f.read()
    parts = data.split("\)")
    for part in parts:
        sections = part.split(",")
        list_firsttxtfile.append(sections[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

If every line of your file contains at least one float, you can extract it using regular expression:

```
import re

first_float = re.compile(r'[-+]?\d*\.?\d+')

with open("firstfile.txt") as txtfile:
    # if line.strip() skips blank lines if any
    list_first_txt_file = [float(first_float.search(line).group()) for line in txtfile if line.strip()]
```

Be aware that if your file contains lines where the regex doesn't match it will fail with `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'group'`. You can change the `if` part of the list-comprehension to `if first_float.search(line)` to avoid that but it will run the regex on the same line twice which might not be great if your files are big.

If you are double sure that there is no blank lines and that each line will have a match, then you can remove the `if` entirely.